# How to find data sets for same time range across multiple products

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a database where I store a 1-minute snapshot for various exchange's product's best bid and ask. I have a requirement where I need to find:

1. 500 best bids and ask across 3 products (`product1 & exch1`, `product2 & exch2`,`product3 & exch3`)
2. All the 500 datapoints should fall within certain time-range e.g. 0900-1014, 1030-1129
3. All 3 products should have same timestamp, i.e., if prod1 doesn't have 1030 datapoint, the query should ignore prod2 and prod3 <-- ***This is where I am stuck***

> I am using MySQL 8.0.35 on Ubuntu 20.04

My table has the following structure

```sql
symbol(varchar)
exchange(varchar)
bid_price(double)
ask_price(double)
timestamp(bigint) # actual best bid ask received time from exchange (millisecond precision)
updated_at(bigint) # minutes precision stored as seconds since epoch e.g. 1702954500102
```

```
symbol,exchange,bid_price,ask_price,timestamp,updated_at
prod1,exch1,555.7,555.8,1702956540603,1702956540
prod1,exch1,555.8,555.9,1702956478591,1702956480
prod1,exch1,555.9,556,1702956420102,1702956420
prod1,exch1,556,556.1,1702956360610,1702956360
prod1,exch1,556,556.1,1702956299607,1702956300
prod1,exch1,556.1,556.2,1702956239595,1702956240
prod1,exch1,556.2,556.3,1702956179597,1702956180
prod1,exch1,556,556.1,1702956122111,1702956120
prod1,exch1,556,556.1,1702956061081,1702956060
prod1,exch1,555.8,555.9,1702955998590,1702956000
prod2,exch2,7.1041,7.1042,1702956600942,1702956600
prod2,exch2,7.104,7.1042,1702956541012,1702956540
prod2,exch2,7.1043,7.1045,1702956480465,1702956480
prod2,exch2,7.1043,7.1044,1702956420617,1702956420
prod2,exch2,7.1043,7.1044,1702956360264,1702956360
prod2,exch2,7.1037,7.1038,1702956300269,1702956300
prod2,exch2,7.1039,7.1041,1702956239092,1702956240
prod2,exch2,7.1041,7.1043,1702956180001,1702956180
prod2,exch2,7.1043,7.1045,1702956123891,1702956120
prod2,exch2,7.1045,7.1047,1702956060588,1702956060
prod3,exch3,72.78,72.79,1702956600332,1702956600
prod3,exch3,72.79,72.8,1702956540698,1702956540
prod3,exch3,72.8,72.81,1702956480542,1702956480
prod3,exch3,72.79,72.81,1702956420228,1702956420
prod3,exch3,72.8,72.81,1702956352133,1702956360
prod3,exch3,72.81,72.82,1702956287733,1702956300
prod3,exch3,72.81,72.82,1702956239441,1702956240
prod3,exch3,72.82,72.83,1702956179253,1702956180
prod3,exch3,72.81,72.82,1702956124140,1702956120
prod3,exch3,72.81,72.82,1702956058999,1702956060
```

With following query I am able to do requirement #1 and #2, but #3 is something I am unable to figure out yet

```sql
(SELECT *, FROM_UNIXTIME(updated_at, '%H%i') AS u_time
FROM algo_system.bbo_1min
WHERE
(
(symbol = 'prod1' AND exchange = 'exch1')
OR
(symbol = 'prod2' AND exchange = 'exch2')
OR
(symbol = 'prod3' AND exchange = 'exch3')
)
HAVING
(u_time >= 900 AND u_time <= 1014)
OR
(u_time >= 1030 AND u_time <= 1129)
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 500)
```

Edit: From the image below, as can see the highlighted red section has prod2 and prod3 data for 21:00 but prod1 doesn't have, I want to remove the prod2 and prod3 data if there is no datapoint for prod1 at 21:00
[image]

Comment: Adding sample data will help you get an answer faster.

Comment: what is `1030 datapoint`? where this comes from?when you limit just 500?

Comment: 1030 is starting range for this range (10:30-11:29) where I need to find the data points within 10:30 AM and 11:29 AM. So I convert the `update_time` with HHMM format (`from_unixtime`) and compare with 10:30.

PS: I have also provided some sample data as per suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sub join or a where exists query may work. Do consider performance also -- I have no idea if the sub query will slow your work down too much.

Apologies for not answering in MySQL.

Here is an example in MsSQL using an inner join -- you can see where I mildly adapted to account for the difference between MsSQL and MySQL. You should be able to work with the idea though.

```
SELECT 
    symbol,
    exchange,
    bid_price,
    ask_price,
    --timestamp,
    FORMAT(dateadd(S, convert(bigint, timestamp) / 1000, '1970-01-01'),'hhmm')+700 AS timestamp,
    --updated_at
    FORMAT(dateadd(S, convert(INT, updated_at), '1970-01-01'),'hhmm')+700 AS updated_at
into #tmp_db
FROM(
    values 
    ('prod1','exch1',7.1041,7.1042, '1702956600942',    '1702956600'), -- 1030 for testing
    ('prod1','exch1',555.7,555.8,   '1702956540603',    '1702956540'),
    ('prod1','exch1',555.8,555.9,   '1702956478591',    '1702956480'),
    ('prod1','exch1',555.9,556,     '1702956420102',    '1702956420'),
    ('prod1','exch1',556,556.1,     '1702956360610',    '1702956360'),
    ('prod1','exch1',556,556.1,     '1702956299607',    '1702956300'),
    ('prod1','exch1',556.1,556.2,   '1702956239595',    '1702956240'),
    ('prod1','exch1',556.2,556.3,   '1702956179597',    '1702956180'),
    ('prod1','exch1',556,556.1,     '1702956122111',    '1702956120'),
    ('prod1','exch1',556,556.1,     '1702956061081',    '1702956060'),
    ('prod1','exch1',555.8,555.9,   '1702955998590',    '1702956000'),
    ('prod2','exch2',7.1041,7.1042, '1702956600942',    '1702956600'), -- 1030 for testing
    ('prod2','exch2',7.104,7.1042,  '1702956541012',    '1702956540'),
    ('prod2','exch2',7.1043,7.1045, '1702956480465',    '1702956480'),
    ('prod2','exch2',7.1043,7.1044, '1702956420617',    '1702956420'),
    ('prod2','exch2',7.1043,7.1044, '1702956360264',    '1702956360'),
    ('prod2','exch2',7.1037,7.1038, '1702956300269',    '1702956300'),
    ('prod2','exch2',7.1039,7.1041, '1702956239092',    '1702956240'),
    ('prod2','exch2',7.1041,7.1043, '1702956180001',    '1702956180'),
    ('prod2','exch2',7.1043,7.1045, '1702956123891',    '1702956120'),
    ('prod2','exch2',7.1045,7.1047, '1702956060588',    '1702956060'),
    ('prod3','exch3',72.78,72.79,   '1702956600332',    '1702956600'), -- 1030 for testing
    ('prod3','exch3',72.79,72.8,    '1702956540698',    '1702956540'),
    ('prod3','exch3',72.8,72.81,    '1702956480542',    '1702956480'),
    ('prod3','exch3',72.79,72.81,   '1702956420228',    '1702956420'),
    ('prod3','exch3',72.8,72.81,    '1702956352133',    '1702956360'),
    ('prod3','exch3',72.81,72.82,   '1702956287733',    '1702956300'),
    ('prod3','exch3',72.81,72.82,   '1702956239441',    '1702956240'),
    ('prod3','exch3',72.82,72.83,   '1702956179253',    '1702956180'),
    ('prod3','exch3',72.81,72.82,   '1702956124140',    '1702956120'),
    ('prod3','exch3',72.81,72.82,   '1702956058999',    '1702956060')

) AS x (symbol, exchange, bid_price, ask_price, timestamp, updated_at)



SELECT top 500
    *
    --FROM_UNIXTIME(updated_at, '%H%i') AS u_time
FROM #tmp_db
JOIN (
        SELECT
            count(DISTINCT symbol) as product_count,
            updated_at as sub_updated_at
        FROM #tmp_db
        WHERE 
            (
                (symbol = 'prod1' AND exchange = 'exch1')
                OR
                (symbol = 'prod2' AND exchange = 'exch2')
                OR
                (symbol = 'prod3' AND exchange = 'exch3')
            )
        GROUP BY updated_at
    ) as x on x.product_count = 3 and x.sub_updated_at = updated_at
WHERE
    (
        (symbol = 'prod1' AND exchange = 'exch1')
        OR
        (symbol = 'prod2' AND exchange = 'exch2')
        OR
        (symbol = 'prod3' AND exchange = 'exch3')
    )
--HAVING
--  (updated_at >= 900 AND updated_at <= 1014)
--  OR
--  (updated_at >= 1030 AND updated_at <= 1129)
and (
        (updated_at >= 900 AND updated_at <= 1014)
        OR
        (updated_at >= 1030 AND updated_at <= 1129)
    )
ORDER BY updated_at DESC --LIMIT 500



drop table #tmp_db
```

all three if the prod1 is included
[image]

none if the prod1 is not showing
[image]

Updated: added "DISTINCT symbol" to ensure all three products are counted, in case a prod can show more than once.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I've got the general idea and able to re-produce for MySQL version for my requirement.

Although yes the performance hit is a little significant (as I had expected), but this is only during initialization and after that the data used will be realtime.

Comment: Regarding performance: The join sub query will run once per row checked. 

To improve this, you could run the sub query and grab all the timestamps that matter and then apply that to the main query. Use two queries or re-write the query so that the query optimizer builds the equivalent plan. Using two queries is simpler.

Also, I assume there is an index on the updated timestamp and symbol with exchange.